# Libcurl test with Gmock unit test gives Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL: Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

Tags: c++, unit-testing, libcurl, googletest, googlemock

I'm using Gmock / Gtest to mock unit tests in c++.

Actual Function to be tested is : which is in c language

```
Class A {
typedef struct response {
    char *payload;
    size_t size;
} response_t;

int curl_fetch_url(CURL *curl, const char *url, response_t *presponse) {

    if (curl == NULL || url == NULL || NULL == presponse) {

        return NULL_POINTER;
    }

    presponse->payload = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(presponse->payload));

    if (presponse->payload == NULL) {
        return FAILED_TO_ALLOCATE_MEMORY;
    }

    presponse->size = 0;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_write_function);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, presponse);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

    CURLcode rcode = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    return rcode;
}
}
```

curl_mocker.h : Here I defined the function to be mocked and tested.

```
class CurlMocker : public CMockMocker<CurlMocker>
{
public:
    **MOCK_CONST_METHOD3(curl_fetch_url, int(void*, const char *, response_t *));**
};
```

Test Class : Unit test is written in C++

```
TEST(curl_rest_call, curl_fetch_url_1) {
#if !defined(__MINGW32__)
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    int expected_ret = NULL_POINTER;
    CurlMocker mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, curl_fetch_url(curl, NULL, NULL)).WillOnce(Return(NULL_POINTER));
    int actual_ret = curl_fetch_url(curl, NULL, NULL); 
    ASSERT_EQ(actual_ret, expected_ret);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
#endif
}

Result : Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, curl_fetch_url(curl, url, &response))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

When I execute the test it runs successfully and ASSERT_EQ(actual_ret, expected_ret); Matches. But still EXPECT_CALL fails and gives : Error

NOTE : The above test works fine when I run it in some other Oracle 7 VM which have libcurl version curl-7.29.0-59.0.3.el7_9.1.x86_64 BUT fails when I run the same on Oracle 8 VM which have libcurl version curl-7.61.1-22.el8.x86_64. Which is strange.

doubt:

- In One of the similar test with some valid data. Mentioned below also gives EXPECT_CALL fails and returns curl code 28 which is rcode in Class A curl_fetch_url funtion. I checked https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html and its CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT (28)Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions.

```
TEST(curl_rest_call, curl_fetch_url_2) {
#if !defined(__MINGW32__)
   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

   int expected_ret = CURLE_OK;
   const char *url = "https://someurl.com/posts/1";
   response_t response;
   response.payload = NULL;
   response.size = 0;

   CurlMocker mock;
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, curl_fetch_url(curl, url, &response)).WillOnce(Return(CURLE_OK));
   int actual_ret = curl_fetch_url(mock,curl, url, &response);
   ASSERT_EQ(actual_ret, expected_ret);

   free(response.payload);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   curl_global_cleanup();
#endif
}

Result : 
Expected equality of these values:
 actual_ret
   Which is: 28
 expected_ret
   Which is: 0
test/curl_rest_call_test.cpp:129: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, curl_fetch_url(curl, url, &response))...
        Expected: to be called once
          Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Basically All my curl_fetch_url(3-4)unit test fails with same EXPECT_CALL fail. Even for NULL check as well (curl_fetch_url_1).
In one of above test(curl_fetch_url_2)it returns CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT which puts me doubt that if  libcurl version is the culprit or I'm doing something wrong? OR there Something is wrong with gtest --- gmock/cmock ?? As same tests are passing in one VM(oracle linux 7) and fails on other VM (oracle linux 8)

Kindly help !

Thanks

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The current code can't compile, due to several syntax errors and private class members.

Answer (score 0):

I Manage to resolve the issue. In curl_mocker.h     `MOCK_CONST_METHOD3(curl_fetch_url, int(void*, const char *, response_t *));`
Virtual function had void* and curl-7.29.0-59.0.3.el7_9.1.x86_64 version doesn't care. Hence it passes in older version. But in updated curl-7.61.1-22.el8.x86_64 version we need to mention type of the parameter we are passing in virtual function so that it can match with actual function i.e  int curl_fetch_url(CURL *curl, const char *url, response_t *presponse) which have CURL *curl type of parameter . After changing void * to CURL * in `MOCK_CONST_METHOD3(curl_fetch_url, int(CURL *, const char *, response_t *));` It started working
Thanks !